# Water-cooled CPU fan makes squeaking noise every 5 seconds

Tags: fan, water-cooling

My Antec 1250 water-cooled CPU fan makes a squeaking noise every 5 seconds.

When it does this, the other fans drop their RPMs down by about 15% for about 1/2 second. I can observe the slowdown by watching the RPM monitor in the BIOS.  So every 5 seconds, I hear a squeak, and then the other fans all slow down a bit.

What could be causing this?  Is the water pump clogged or blocked?

Here is a video that demonstrates the noise:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyubNZeZkuk
```

EDIT: In BIOS, under Voltage, it reads

```
CPU = 1.28V
5V = 4.97V
3.3V = 3.24V
12V = 11.94V
```

Comment: confirm that you are not almost at max power capacity.

Comment: I added an edit to indicate voltage levels, is that what you mean?

Comment: I am more concerned with overall wattage and whether you are just under the line your Powersupply and AC source are providing. Do you have a UPS? its usually easiest to evaluate at the wall.

Comment: No, I am not on a UPS. It's plugged directly into the wall.

Comment: Sounds like a power issue or a thermistor fault. What is your power supply?

Comment: I have a Corsair HX850i power supply -- 850 watts.